# Concatenate with column header but omit blanks with Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I want to modify this formula:

```
=A$1&": "&A4&" & "&B$1&": "&B4
```

Sample: Column A: *a info* & Column B: *b info*

So that if there is a blank cell the Title and the blank field don't show up.

- If A was blank, this is what I want to see:

  Column B: *b info*
- If B was blank, this is what I want to see:

  Column A: *a info*

And if both fields are blank, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

=IF(LEN(A4),A$1&": "&A4,"")&IF(COUNTA(A4:B4)=2," & ","")&IF(LEN(B4),B$1&": "&B4,)

[image]

Edit after comment: If a formula returns an empty string into the cells that are checked, you need to factor that in. Consider

```
=IF(LEN(AK2),AK$1&": "&AK2,"")&IF(AND(LEN(AK2&AL2)>0,COUNTA(AK2:AL2)=2)," & ","")&IF(LEN(AL2),AL$1&": "&AL2,)
```

The ampersand sign will now only be included if there is content in any of the two monitored cells. See the screenshot where the formula in AM5 does not return anything, because both AK5 and AL5 are empty.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That formula worked on my "test" spreadsheet, but when I tried to modify it for my "real" spreadsheet, the ampersand sign shows up if the cell is blank. I *thought* I modified the formula correctly, but something is not quite right. Do you see something wrong: =IF(LEN(AK2),AK$1&": "&AK2,"")&IF(COUNTA(AK2:AL2)=2," & ","")&IF(LEN(AL2),AL$1&": "&AL2,)

Comment: It looks like your "Real" sheet has a formula that pushes an empty string into the cell, like =If(true,"value","")  -- The "false" value is an empty string and will be counted. I wish you would include details like that in your question. An empty cell is not the same as a cell that contains a formula that returns a "" string.

Comment: I added an adjusted formula

Comment: Thank you Teylyn! I didn't realize (and don't think) that the formula was pushing an empty string in to the cell....So your revised formula works, except that the ampersand sign is still showing up with the AL cell is "empty"/"blank"

Comment: Not if the cell is truly empty. What is in the cell? Post the formula or the exact contents.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: I believe the cell is truly "empty" - there is no data or formula in the cell. When I use your formula above: =IF(LEN(AK2),AK$1&": "&AK2,"")&IF(AND(LEN(AK2&AL2)>0,COUNTA(AK2:AL2)=2)," & ","")&IF(LEN(AL2),AL$1&": "&AL2,) I still get an ampersand if the cell is empty. I don't know how to post a screenshot.

Comment: Screen Shot 2015-06-22 at 9.25.18 AM

Comment: You were right...there IS something in the cell, only it's not "visible". When I "delete" the empty cell, the ampersand goes away. Although I'm not entirely sure what is in those cells that is displaying as blank or empty, but there is something actually there.  There is no formula in the cell. The content came from a database list. Now I just have to figure out how to mass delete these non-empty blank cells! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: So...now I've determined that I need to ADD another column of data to this formula (I erroneously though I could add some information to a cell with concatenated data...). But of course, I couldn't modify the formula properly. Would you please post another version of the formula to concatenate AJ, AK and AL with the same paramenters (only display if there is content, include Title, and include ampersand between concatenated data. I tried modifying your formula and got the following 3 results: 1) AJ title: sss & FALSE 2) AJ title: sssAK title: ttt 3) AJ title: sss & AK title: total title: tat

Comment: for your amusement, here is how I tried to edit the formula: =IF(LEN(AJ2),AJ$1&": "&AJ2,"")&IF(AND(LEN(AJ2&AK2&AL2)>0,COUNTA(AJ2:AL2)=3)," & ","")&IF(LEN(AK2),AK$1&": "&AK2,)&IF(LEN(AL2),AL$1&": "&AL2)